# Custom Calendar inflation error in Grid Cell

Tags: android, adapter, layout-inflater

MainActivity.class

```
@Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.member_profile);


                _calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
                month = _calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
                year = _calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                Log.d(tag, "Calendar Instance:= " + "Month: " + month + " " + "Year: "
                        + year);

                selectedDayMonthYearButton = (Button) this
                        .findViewById(R.id.selectedDayMonthYear);
                selectedDayMonthYearButton.setText("Selected: ");

                prevMonth = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.prevMonth);
                prevMonth.setOnClickListener(this);

                currentMonth = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.currentMonth);
                currentMonth.setText(DateFormat.format(dateTemplate,
                        _calendar.getTime()));

                nextMonth = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.nextMonth);
                nextMonth.setOnClickListener(this);

                calendarView = (GridView) this.findViewById(R.id.calendar);

                // Initialised
                adapter = new GridCellAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.id.calendar_day_gridcell, month, year);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
               calendarView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
     private void setGridCellAdapterToDate(int month, int year) {
            adapter = new GridCellAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                    R.id.calendar_day_gridcell, month, year);
            _calendar.set(year, month - 1, _calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            currentMonth.setText(DateFormat.format(dateTemplate,
                    _calendar.getTime()));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            calendarView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v == prevMonth) {
                if (month <= 1) {
                    month = 12;
                    year--;
                } else {
                    month--;
                }
                Log.d(tag, "Setting Prev Month in GridCellAdapter: " + "Month: "
                        + month + " Year: " + year);
                setGridCellAdapterToDate(month, year);
            }
            if (v == nextMonth) {
                if (month > 11) {
                    month = 1;
                    year++;
                } else {
                    month++;
                }
                Log.d(tag, "Setting Next Month in GridCellAdapter: " + "Month: "
                        + month + " Year: " + year);
                setGridCellAdapterToDate(month, year);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            Log.d(tag, "Destroying View ...");
            super.onDestroy();
        }
```

This is the main activity class then the code jumps to the adapter class where I get the problem when inflating my xml code for the adapter in getView()

GridCellAdapter.class

```
public class GridCellAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements View.OnClickListener {
    private static final String tag = "GridCellAdapter";
    private final Context _context;

    private final List<String> list;
    private static final int DAY_OFFSET = 1;
    private final String[] weekdays = new String[] { "Sun", "Mon", "Tue",
            "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" };
    private final String[] months = { "January", "February", "March",
            "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
            "October", "November", "December" };
    private final int[] daysOfMonth = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30,
            31, 30, 31 };
    private int daysInMonth;
    private int currentDayOfMonth;
    private int currentWeekDay;
    private Button gridcell;
    private TextView num_events_per_day;
    private Button selectedDayMonthYearButton;
    private final HashMap<String, Integer> eventsPerMonthMap;
    private final SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "dd-MMM-yyyy");

    // Days in Current Month
    public GridCellAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                           int month, int year) {
        super();
        this._context = context;
        this.list = new ArrayList<String>();
        Log.d(tag, "==> Passed in Date FOR Month: " + month + " "
                + "Year: " + year);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        setCurrentDayOfMonth(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        setCurrentWeekDay(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
        Log.d(tag, "New Calendar:= " + calendar.getTime().toString());
        Log.d(tag, "CurrentDayOfWeek :" + getCurrentWeekDay());
        Log.d(tag, "CurrentDayOfMonth :" + getCurrentDayOfMonth());

        // Print Month
        printMonth(month, year);

        // Find Number of Events
        eventsPerMonthMap = findNumberOfEventsPerMonth(year, month);
    }

    private String getMonthAsString(int i) {
        return months[i];
    }

    private String getWeekDayAsString(int i) {
        return weekdays[i];
    }

    private int getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(int i) {
        return daysOfMonth[i];
    }

    public String getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    /**
     * Prints Month
     *
     * @param mm
     * @param yy
     */
    private void printMonth(int mm, int yy) {
        Log.d(tag, "==> printMonth: mm: " + mm + " " + "yy: " + yy);
        int trailingSpaces = 0;
        int daysInPrevMonth = 0;
        int prevMonth = 0;
        int prevYear = 0;
        int nextMonth = 0;
        int nextYear = 0;

        int currentMonth = mm - 1;
        String currentMonthName = getMonthAsString(currentMonth);
        daysInMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(currentMonth);

        Log.d(tag, "Current Month: " + " " + currentMonthName + " having "
                + daysInMonth + " days.");

        GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(yy, currentMonth, 1);
        Log.d(tag, "Gregorian Calendar:= " + cal.getTime().toString());

        if (currentMonth == 11) {
            prevMonth = currentMonth - 1;
            daysInPrevMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(prevMonth);
            nextMonth = 0;
            prevYear = yy;
            nextYear = yy + 1;
            Log.d(tag, "*->PrevYear: " + prevYear + " PrevMonth:"
                    + prevMonth + " NextMonth: " + nextMonth
                    + " NextYear: " + nextYear);
        } else if (currentMonth == 0) {
            prevMonth = 11;
            prevYear = yy - 1;
            nextYear = yy;
            daysInPrevMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(prevMonth);
            nextMonth = 1;
            Log.d(tag, "**--> PrevYear: " + prevYear + " PrevMonth:"
                    + prevMonth + " NextMonth: " + nextMonth
                    + " NextYear: " + nextYear);
        } else {
            prevMonth = currentMonth - 1;
            nextMonth = currentMonth + 1;
            nextYear = yy;
            prevYear = yy;
            daysInPrevMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(prevMonth);
            Log.d(tag, "***---> PrevYear: " + prevYear + " PrevMonth:"
                    + prevMonth + " NextMonth: " + nextMonth
                    + " NextYear: " + nextYear);
        }

        int currentWeekDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1;
        trailingSpaces = currentWeekDay;

        Log.d(tag, "Week Day:" + currentWeekDay + " is "
                + getWeekDayAsString(currentWeekDay));
        Log.d(tag, "No. Trailing space to Add: " + trailingSpaces);
        Log.d(tag, "No. of Days in Previous Month: " + daysInPrevMonth);

        if (cal.isLeapYear(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)))
            if (mm == 2)
                ++daysInMonth;
            else if (mm == 3)
                ++daysInPrevMonth;

        // Trailing Month days
        for (int i = 0; i < trailingSpaces; i++) {
            Log.d(tag,
                    "PREV MONTH:= "
                            + prevMonth
                            + " => "
                            + getMonthAsString(prevMonth)
                            + " "
                            + String.valueOf((daysInPrevMonth
                            - trailingSpaces + DAY_OFFSET)
                            + i));
            list.add(String
                    .valueOf((daysInPrevMonth - trailingSpaces + DAY_OFFSET)
                            + i)
                    + "-GREY"
                    + "-"
                    + getMonthAsString(prevMonth)
                    + "-"
                    + prevYear);
        }

        // Current Month Days
        for (int i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++) {
            Log.d(currentMonthName, String.valueOf(i) + " "
                    + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + " " + yy);
            if (i == getCurrentDayOfMonth()) {
                list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-BLUE" + "-"
                        + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy);
            } else {
                list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-WHITE" + "-"
                        + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy);
            }
        }

        // Leading Month days
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size() % 7; i++) {
            Log.d(tag, "NEXT MONTH:= " + getMonthAsString(nextMonth));
            list.add(String.valueOf(i + 1) + "-GREY" + "-"
                    + getMonthAsString(nextMonth) + "-" + nextYear);
        }
    }

    /**
     * NOTE: YOU NEED TO IMPLEMENT THIS PART Given the YEAR, MONTH, retrieve
     * ALL entries from a SQLite database for that month. Iterate over the
     * List of All entries, and get the dateCreated, which is converted into
     * day.
     *
     * @param year
     * @param month
     * @return
     */
    private HashMap<String, Integer> findNumberOfEventsPerMonth(int year,
                                                                int month) {
        HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        return map;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridecell, parent, false);
        }

        // Get a reference to the Day gridcell
        gridcell = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.calendar_day_gridcell);
        gridcell.setOnClickListener(this);

        // ACCOUNT FOR SPACING

        Log.d(tag, "Current Day: " + getCurrentDayOfMonth());
        String[] day_color = list.get(position).split("-");
        String theday = day_color[0];
        String themonth = day_color[2];
        String theyear = day_color[3];
        if ((!eventsPerMonthMap.isEmpty()) && (eventsPerMonthMap != null)) {
            if (eventsPerMonthMap.containsKey(theday)) {
                num_events_per_day = (TextView) row
                        .findViewById(R.id.num_events_per_day);
                Integer numEvents = (Integer) eventsPerMonthMap.get(theday);
                num_events_per_day.setText(numEvents.toString());
            }
        }

        // Set the Day GridCell
        gridcell.setText(theday);
        gridcell.setTag(theday + "-" + themonth + "-" + theyear);
        Log.d(tag, "Setting GridCell " + theday + "-" + themonth + "-"
                + theyear);


        return row;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String date_month_year = (String) view.getTag();
        selectedDayMonthYearButton.setText("Selected: " + date_month_year);
        Log.e("Selected date", date_month_year);
        try {
            Date parsedDate = dateFormatter.parse(date_month_year);
            Log.d(tag, "Parsed Date: " + parsedDate.toString());

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public int getCurrentDayOfMonth() {
        return currentDayOfMonth;
    }

    private void setCurrentDayOfMonth(int currentDayOfMonth) {
        this.currentDayOfMonth = currentDayOfMonth;
    }

    public void setCurrentWeekDay(int currentWeekDay) {
        this.currentWeekDay = currentWeekDay;
    }

    public int getCurrentWeekDay() {
        return currentWeekDay;
    }
}
```

gridecell.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/calendar_button_selector"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/calendar_day_gridcell"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/calendar_button_selector"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >
    </Button>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/num_events_per_day"
        style="@style/calendar_event_style"
        android:layout_width="10dip"
        android:layout_height="10dip"
        android:layout_gravity="right" >
    </TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

member_profile

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    >


<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="800dp">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="800dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="385dp"
            android:layout_height="210dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView3" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" Noah Tanenholtz"
            android:textSize="28dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_gravity="left|bottom" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:background= "@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/lightgray"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/buttonlayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="60sp"
            android:background="@color/teal"
            android:gravity="left|top"
            android:height="60sp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/prevMonth"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
                android:src="@mipmap/back" >
            </ImageView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/currentMonth"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="60sp"
                android:layout_weight="0.6"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="December"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >
            </TextView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/nextMonth"
                android:layout_width="50sp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginRight="10sp"
                android:src="@mipmap/next" >
            </ImageView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/selectedDayMonthYear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >
        </Button>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:text="Sun"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="9dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:text="Mon"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:text="Tue"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:text="Wed"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:text="Thu"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/textView10"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:text="Fri"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView10"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView10"
                android:layout_marginLeft="32dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:text="Sat"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/textView12"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/calendar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:numColumns="7" >
        </GridView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:id="@+id/listView2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text=" Followers:"
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:textSize="32dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
    </FrameLayout>
    <ListView android:id="@+id/slider_list"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider= "@color/teal"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"

        />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Please help I would rather use CalendarView but it is very buggy and all I need is to create a custom calendar view that works. It show the month picker and days of the week but not the actual days if I don't set the adapter.

Comment: Post member_profile.xml. May be if you have shown custom view in xml.

Comment: Yes I will add it, sorry I have been busy with another app that I am going to submit to the Google Play Store soon.